# How can I get params from the url in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, next.js

When I click on the button, I try to go to the page where the information comes according to the id.
but when I click on the button, nothing comes up

my index.js

```
<Link href={`/conditions/${sub.id}`} passHref>
  <a>
   Button
  </a>
</Link>
```

my [slug].js

```
import React from 'react'

function Entry ({sub}) {

  return (
    <>
    {sub.header}
    </>
  )
}
export default Entry;
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) =>
{
  const { slug } = ctx.params;

  const response = await get(`localhost:1337/sub/${slug}`);

  return {
    props: {
      sub: response.data,
    },
  };
};
```

this is my codes with next js, but I can't get params. 
Params how to get it in the page?

Comment: what is your files structure?

Comment: if you are asking about the structure of the database in json format, i am developing my project with next js, and for the back end part, I use a strapi

Comment: no I meant your project files' structure

Comment: are you asking if there is a react js?

Comment: no, I'm just asking about how you're structuring your project, something like [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--ydNJXMdo--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/articles/d1jbknv7im8dgpjod602.png)

Comment: my file format is as shown in the picture

Comment: which picture? anyway, if `sub.js` is the file where you want to get the params it should be named `[slug].js` since you're getting `slug` from `ctx.params`

Comment: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Untitled_415.png > my file structor

Comment: and I don't understand what you mean

Comment: in your files structure you have `/conditions/conditionalTabs/[slug].js` and you're linking to the wrong path `/conditions/${sub.id}`, try this `/conditions/conditionalTabs/${sub.id}`